# Google Sheet JOIN 3 Tables related

Tags: join, google-sheets

I have 3 sheets with relations via key:

Names:

*CONTRACT*

```
`(COMPANY | CONTRACT_ID | CONTRACT_Head | CONTRACT_Value)`
```

*INVOICE*

```
`(CONTRACT_ID | INVOICE_ID | INVOICE_Head | INVOICE_Value)`
```

*PAYMENTS*

```
`(INVOICE_ID | PAY_ID | PAY_Head | PAY_Value)`
```

here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18bcs1IW-k1HeOFcsns6xbtXQQ2i5hKg3M4mABcpVI6o/edit#gid=0

I want to make a formula that makes a join 3 tables without aggregation and using key fields ...  something like [*FINAL* Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18bcs1IW-k1HeOFcsns6xbtXQQ2i5hKg3M4mABcpVI6o/edit#gid=249318555)

Note that some Invoice can haven´t payments relative, or
that some Contract can haven´t any invoice

I intended to use ArrayFormula, but can't get work

Comment: Nope, thats is working over DataStudio. In this case, the perspective is over Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({
 PAYMENT!A2:D\
 VLOOKUP(PAYMENT!A2:A; {INVOICE!B1:D\INVOICE!A1:A}; {1\2\3\4}; 0)\
 VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(PAYMENT!A2:A; {INVOICE!B1:D\INVOICE!A1:A}; 4; 0); {CONTRACT!B1:D\CONTRACT!A1:A}; {1\2\3\4}; 0)});
 "SELECT Col12, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col2, Col3, Col4 order by Col2"; 0)
```

[image]

Comment: It missing two rows .Where Invoice don't have any paymets, and where contract haven't any invoice. That is where i fail